# Opening TO date, after selecting FROM date in datepicker range using each

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I got a calendar range on a page, consisting of two inputs, #from-date and #to-date. If I select from date, I want the to date to be shown automatically.

HTML markup:

```
<div class="calendar-range">
    <div class="filter-first date-from">
        <input type="text" id="from-date" class="form-control form-control-main calendar-from datepicker">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="filter date-to">
        <input type="text" id="to-date" class="form-control form-control-main calendar-to datepicker">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
body.find(".calendar-range").each(function (index, callback) {
    var selectedToElement = $(this).find('.calendar-to');
    var selectedToDay = selectedToElement.datepicker('getDate');
    var selectedFromElement = $(this).find('.calendar-from');
    var selectedFromDay = selectedFromElement.datepicker('getDate');
    var numberOfMonths = 2;

    if (body.width() < 768) {
        numberOfMonths = 1;
    }

    var settings = {
        changeMonth: false,
        numberOfMonths: numberOfMonths,
        dateFormat: dateFormat,
        minDate: new Date(Date.now()),
        maxDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)),
        onSelect: function (dateText, object) {
            selectedToDay = selectedToElement.datepicker('getDate');
            selectedFromDay = selectedFromElement.datepicker('getDate');

            selectedToElement.change();
            selectedFromElement.change();

            if ($(this).hasClass('calendar-from')) {
                to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this.value));
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('calendar-to')) {
                from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this.value));
            }
        },
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            selectedToDay = selectedToElement.datepicker('getDate');
            selectedFromDay = selectedFromElement.datepicker('getDate');
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var d = date.getTime();
            var cssClass = 'selected-date-range';
            var defaultClass = '';

            if (selectedToDay != null && d == selectedToDay.getTime()) {
                cssClass = cssClass + ' selected-date-range-last';
                defaultClass = defaultClass + ' selected-date-range-last';
            } else if (selectedFromDay != null && d == selectedFromDay.getTime()) {
                cssClass = cssClass + ' selected-date-range-first';
                defaultClass = defaultClass + ' selected-date-range-first';
            }

            if (selectedFromDay != null && selectedToDay != null && d <= selectedToDay.getTime() && d >= selectedFromDay.getTime()) {
                return [true, cssClass, ''];
            }
            return [true, defaultClass, ''];
        },
        onClose: function (input, object) {
            if (object.id === "from-date") {
                to.datepicker("show");
            }
        }
    };

    var from = selectedFromElement.datepicker(settings);
    var to = selectedToElement.datepicker(settings);
});
```

I tried solving it with onClose, but this seems to iterate twice, and close the opened #to-date too. Is it possible to implement it without separating the two datepickers? (also something really weird happens with hiding/showing the datepickers)

Help appreciated, thx.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the to date to be shown automatically"?

Comment: There are a number of undefined functions in your example. Also, you attempt to call `getDate` before you initialize `.datepicker()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of improvements you can make. Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mcqra47o/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var body = $("body");
  var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy";
  $(".calendar-range").each(function(index, callback) {
    var selectedToElement = $(this).find('.calendar-to');
    var selectedToDay = selectedToElement.val().length ? selectedToElement.datepicker('getDate') : new Date;
    var selectedFromElement = $(this).find('.calendar-from');
    var selectedFromDay = selectedFromElement.val().length ? selectedFromElement.datepicker('getDate') : new Date;
    var numberOfMonths = 2;

    if (body.width() < 768) {
      numberOfMonths = 1;
    }

    var settings = {
      changeMonth: false,
      numberOfMonths: numberOfMonths,
      dateFormat: dateFormat,
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: "+1y",
      onSelect: function(dateText, object) {
        selectedToDay = selectedToElement.datepicker('getDate');
        selectedFromDay = selectedFromElement.datepicker('getDate');
        /*
        selectedToElement.change();
        selectedFromElement.change();
        */
        if ($(this).hasClass('calendar-from')) {
          selectedToElement.datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('calendar-to')) {
          selectedFromElement.datepicker("option", "maxDate", dateText);
        }
      },
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        selectedToDay = selectedToElement.datepicker('getDate');
        selectedFromDay = selectedFromElement.datepicker('getDate');
      },
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var d = date.getTime();
        var cssClass = 'selected-date-range';
        var defaultClass = '';
        if (selectedToDay != null && d == selectedToDay.getTime()) {
          cssClass = cssClass + ' selected-date-range-last';
          defaultClass = defaultClass + ' selected-date-range-last';
        } else if (selectedFromDay != null && d == selectedFromDay.getTime()) {
          cssClass = cssClass + ' selected-date-range-first';
          defaultClass = defaultClass + ' selected-date-range-first';
        }

        if (selectedFromDay != null && selectedToDay != null && d <= selectedToDay.getTime() && d >= selectedFromDay.getTime()) {
          return [true, cssClass, ''];
        }
        return [true, defaultClass, ''];
      },
      /*
      onClose: function(input, object) {
        if (object.id === "from-date") {
          to.datepicker("show");
        }
      }
      */
    };

    var from = selectedFromElement.datepicker(settings);
    var to = selectedToElement.datepicker(settings);
  });
});
```

First, we should not call `.datepicker()` to `getDate` before it's been initialized. So to set the following variables early, we can do this:

```
var selectedToDay = selectedToElement.val().length ? selectedToElement.datepicker('getDate') : new Date;
var selectedFromDay = selectedFromElement.val().length ? selectedFromElement.datepicker('getDate') : new Date;
```

For `minDate` and `maxDate`, we can check the API and see:

> Multiple types supported:
>
> - **Date:** A date object containing the minimum date.
> - **Number:** A number of days from today. For example `2` represents two days from today and `-1` represents yesterday.
> - **String:** A string in the format defined by the `dateFormat` option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are `"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, and `"d"` for days. For example, `"+1m +7d"` represents one month and seven days from today.

I suggest using relative date formats if possible. For today, I used `0`, and for 1 year, I used `"+1y"`.

When a selection is made `change` is fired anyway, so I commented this out. If it is needed for something else, I would suggest looking at `.tragger("change")`.

The `onSelect` option passes `dateText` in, so we can use that to set the new `minDate` and `maxDate` as needed.

Hopefully that addresses everything and works as you'd desired.

Comment: Hey, thx, those improvements are useful. But I need that autoswitch to the second date after I select the "from" date.

Comment: You can use the `setDate` method or via `.val()`.